# What is net.one97.paytm ? I know it opens paytm app but what is it? And how can I find one for paypal?

Tags: android, android-intent, paypal, paytm

Many answers are on "How to INTEGRATE Paypal or Paytm on android app". But what I want is how to just "OPEN" the application using Intent or something.

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("net.one97.paytm");
startActivity(i);
```

Opens the paytm app on the mobile.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`net.one97.paytm` is the package name of PayTM app. Package name uniquely identifies an Android application.

To just open PayPal app use `com.paypal.android.p2pmobile` as package name.

**Note:** Simplest way to find the package name of any Android app is to look for it on the Google Play store like below image.

[image]

A simple explanation is here https://documentation.meraki.com/SM/Apps_and_Software/Searching_for_Android_apps_by_a_package_name_ID